# How to query objects with property contains a value in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a model `event` which referenceMany `user`.

```
"relations": {
  "attendees": {
    "type": "referencesMany",
    "model": "user",
    "foreignKey": "attendeeIds",
    "options": {
      "validate": true,
      "forceId": false,
      "persistent": true
   }
}
```

How can I query event which `attendees` property contain a given value? `attendees` is an array containing userId.

For example:

```
Event.find({
    where: {
      attendees: {
        contains: givenUserId
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called **'Filter on level 2 properties'** as referenced [**here**](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517?djatyReqId=14790430203156783721.419424622_github.com) and is being implemented for Memory and MongoDB connectors. It still has some issues.
For SQL connectors, this isn't supported yet and - as mentioned also inside this open discussion link - it requires some time which cannot be afforded now.

Possible work around [**here**](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517?djatyReqId=14790430203156783721.419424622_github.com#issuecomment-239039066) with **regexp** that would apply to the underlying JSON string and executing SQL directly via **[datasource.connector.execute()](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Executing-native-SQL.html)**

**Simple implementaion could be:**

```
AnyModel.getApp((err, app) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  }

  // Using MySQL
  const MySQL = app.dataSources.MySQL;

  MySQL.connector.execute(`select * from Table where column like '%${string}%'`,
    [], {}, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
      }

      console.log(data);
      next();
    });
});
```